# How should user supplied links be validated?

Tags: web-application

I want to create an internet forum where users can copy and paste links to external URLs within a thread. What measures should be taken to lessen the likelihood that links posted do not have malicious intent?

Comment: please consider the following, and edit your question if you're able to provide more info: will users that can post links have to be logged in? will there be any flagging mechanism? will there be an admin or moderator gateway before or after the link is published? do you intend giving the end-user the direct link, or, will your site redirect through some 'outgoing' function?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer these questions given I don't have experience doing this. I was just looking for common practices, guidance in how to proceed.

Comment: Aside from strict security features, consider building moderation features: limiting how many links new users can create, making it easy for mods to find potential spam, and making it possible to put URL patterns onto a blocklist.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, there is no way to be sure a link isn't malicious. Even links to well-known and trustworthy sites could be a watering hole attack to exploit a vulnerability on the site (e.g. XSS). Additionally, URL parsing is a tricky subject, and trying to determine what the browser will do with a particular URL is surprisingly failure-prone. However, there are a few things you can do:

1. Restrict URI schemes. Allow HTTPS, and probably also HTTP, but don't allow anything else. Certainly don't allow javascript: or data: URIs, as those can be used for script injection (XSS) on your site.
2. Either disallow IP addresses as the host (in place of the domain) entirely, or at least require that they not be loopback addresses (127.*.*.*), local network addresses (192.168.*.*, or 10.*.*.*) or automatic private addresses (169.254.*.*), or the IPv6 equivalents. If this is an Internet forum, there's no reason to expect that another user's local address will resolve to the same machine as it would for the poster, so at best the link won't work and likely it'll be worse than that.

Beyond that, one important consideration is that you should probably *not* attempt to resolve the address, much less send the request and render the page, yourself (on your server, automatically). Doing so puts your servers and internal infrastructure at needless risk of SSRF (Server-Side Request Forgery), a common attack where a server is tricked into making requests to malicious endpoints, or to endpoints that the attacker can't reach or possibly even can't resolve, but wants to probe (e.g. endpoints inside a firewall).